# Is there anything against using Cloud Run for a server side GTM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager, google-cloud-run, app-engine-flexible

I have been setting up several server side GTMs for my company in the last months. I have deployed both App Engine Flexible versions, as well as Cloud Run hosted ssGTMs.

I found using Cloud Run easier to setup and also cheaper as long as you stay under 300 million requests per month. Custom domain setup is also only slightly different.

[The official documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/script-user-guide) Basically only covers App Engine and Manual deployment.

I was wondering if there is any downside towards using Cloud Run for hosting your ssGTM besides potential cold starts (which I do not really care about).

Comment: I found that: https://code.markedmondson.me/gtm-serverside-cloudrun/

Comment: Not important enough for an answer, but you won't get automatic IP to Geo resolution, because adding Geo headers is a feature of app engine, not GTM itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with GTM but here are few things for using Cloud Run you have to figure out first.

- Is GTM completley stateless ? Or does it needs State, Cloud Run doesn't offer a filesystem kind capabilities for storing files on disk
- Is GTM already available as a container ?
- You can avoid cold starts by setting the min replicas to 1 or higher so that there is at least always 1 instance available to serve traffic.

Comment: Hi @MarkdeHaan, please consider accepting and upvoting if the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) was helpful for you

Comment: I accepted this answer because these are good considerations. Server side GTM is available as a docker container gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable, and it is stateless as the only thing it does is route GTM information to additional third parties.

I personally prefer Cloud Run because of the available docker image and you can use the interface to deploy it.

Comment: Thank you, i checked the setup script from the link in your initial question and it's quite long and does setup a bunch of things. So i'm not sure how easy or complicated it will be to deploy GTM to Cloud Run. I will try to reach out to the internal team in charge. Meanwhile if you manage to do so let us know please ;)

Comment: I managed to deploy a production + preview server following the link Guillaume posted in my initial post. https://code.markedmondson.me/gtm-serverside-cloudrun/

I had it up and running in ~20 minutes. The only big differences I can see is the scale to 0 with Cloud Run vs the 1 instance on Flex App Engine AND the custom domain mapping. If you want to map a custom domain, for Cloud Run you need to use Firebase hosting.